# How to get environment variable in .NET Core worker service running on linux

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables

I am trying to retrieve an environment variable in an ASP.NET Core worker service which runs on a Linux environment in a container.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key"></param>
    /// <param name="defaultValueIfNotFound"></param>
    public static T GetConfigValue<T>(string key, T defaultValueIfNotFound)
    {
        string? variableValue = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(key);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(variableValue))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {variableValue}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Environment variable {key} not set.");
            return defaultValueIfNotFound;
        }

        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(variableValue, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException($"Failed to cast the settings value with key {key}");
        }
    }
```

It does not seem to work when I deploy it into the Linux container.

When I search the web, I can't find anything that actually confirms it's possible or how to do it?

Comment: I would make a couple of changes.... First I would inject the environment variables into my config object.  Second in Linux Env variables work in a funny way...  Use all caps to set them and use all caps to get them...

Comment: Also you need to provide more information about what is happening. Are there errors? is just null? What is happening?

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro it just returns false.